# The import android.app.WallpaperManager cannot be resolved

Tags: android, import

I can't imagine why it won't let me import this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you're targetting a high enough SDK version? The WallpaperManager has only been included [since API Level 5](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html). This means your manifest.xml you should have

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
```

Comment: Yes after an exhaustive search of developer.android.com i finally uncovered that info. but now i don't know how to set the wallpaper. i am testing on my phone which will only allow me to use sdk version 3. i was following the sample from the android sdk pack.

Comment: Well you can use reflection to test for sdk version and then use a different method for lower versions of Android. Try googling for some of Mark Murphy's compatibility/fragmentation stuff on how do reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the project's `default.properties` to target the right SDK version. This is originally generated by the android tool. In the case of something I'm working on right now, I had to change

```
target=android-3
```

to

```
target=android-7
```

I also made the abovementioned addition to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="5" />
```

But I'm not certain that's required. It may be desireable anyway though.